# Re-index an existing ElasticSearch index to updated templates

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to make an existing index or a set of indices re-index to match the most recent version of matching templates? By re-index I mean change their mappings and settings to match what is in the template.

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, you can't do it easily.
That said, there's a feature request that can help in the future but only if you didn't disable _source.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1077

What you can do in the meantime is to use a script to scan and scroll your index and reindex it in another index.

HTH